# iPhone 5 views not resizing to correct width

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, ios6

I do not use auto layout and I set all my views to autoresize their subviews.
My subviews will not get the correct width and I do the following hack:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    if([CEDeviceUtils isPhone5])
    {
        NSUInteger width = [CEViewUtils windowSize].width;
        if(width != 568) width = 568;
        [CEViewUtils sizeView:self atWidth:width];
    }
  }
```

isPhone5, windowSize and sizeView are just some utility methods that I use and their implementation is not important for my question.

I do not like having to use this hack and I must be missing something. Any clues on how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The 4" Retina display has a 320 x 568 effective resolution, with the 568 pt being the height. I'm assuming you're using a landscape orientation by the fact that you're checking if the `width` property is 568, but are you sure your `[CEViewUtils windowSize].width` isn't returning the 320 pt width of the device in the default portrait orientation? You should probably just be looking at the `height` property regardless of the current state of device rotation.

Also, it can't hurt to check that your `isPhone5` method is actually returning the correct value; throw an `NSLog()` or breakpoint in your code to make sure control reaches where you expect it to. (Same goes for the `awakeFromNib` method -- make sure it's getting called when you expect it to be. You may need to move this code into the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` methods, which are called after the view metrics have been established, so you can override them.)

Comment: window size returns 480, it is using rootViewController.view.bounds.size

Comment: you are right I am having the app in landscape orientation, the size returns 480 while it should have been 568

Comment: Can you post your code for `[CEViewUtils windowSize]`? Usually you want to check `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height` for the 4" Retina resolution of 568 pts.

Comment: + (CGSize)windowSize
{
    UIApplicationDelegate * delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    return delegate.window.rootViewController.view.bounds.size;
}

Comment: I check the width because the app is landscape only, and using bounds takes into account any rotation, if I used frame instead of bounds it would be incorrect.

Comment: Okay got it, so the problem is that the view isn't sizing correctly even though control is reaching this line with `width = 568`: `[CEViewUtils sizeView:self atWidth:width];` Assuming that method does work correctly, try my suggestion of moving this code to the `viewDidLoad` method. (Or even `viewDidAppear` to be absolutely certain all other autosizing and such has taken place before you override it.)

Comment: well... what I am looking for is not having to use the hack. regarding the iPhone 5 etc, I have spent hours making sure the hack works and all the method it uses as well.

Comment: so if say viewDidAppear is ok, should I add all my subviews there?

Comment: width still 480, in viewDidAppear when running the iPhone 5 simulator

Comment: You'll have to post some more information about your view layout and hierarchy as well as what autosizing masks you have set (springs and struts). Depending on how complex your view setup is, you may not be able to get around either using this kind of code or switching to Auto Layout.